# Ubuntu 20.04 keyboard and mouse not working but ssh still work after idle for a while

Tags: ubuntu

Currently I can ssh into this PC and all services like web... also fine, but I can't wake it up by using my mouse and keyboard.

After I replugged in keyboard, I found the num lock and caps lock aren't working since the lights didn't turn on. But I'm sure the power supply is good because the mouse light works fine.

Is there anyway to resolve this problem without reboot it?

Comment: Works after reboot it, but I still don't have any idea why this happend.